# Debugging Linux process hangs, which code is it running?

Tags: c, linux, debugging

I have a process running on a very weak Linux embedded device, which could not run gdb / gdb server on itself. I let it provoking a function X from a shared library repeatedly (there are also some others process calling it at the same time with much less frequency), it usually hangs somewhere inside the shared library after 1 day or a half-day. How do I debug:

- In case it blocked somewhere: which is the last line of code it ran?
- In case it stuck in an infinite loop: which lines of code it running?

What I tried:

- I dig into the shared library and put a lot of syslog inside to check. However, with a very high amount of syslog being called constantly, my process now hangs every 2-5 minutes. I think syslog is blocked by UNIX socket?

Comment: If you have the source for the library, can’t you just connect with a debugger and get a backtrace?

Comment: Unfortunately, I use a very weak embedded device, which couldn't be debugged by gdb or gdb server.

Comment: Why not? Don’t have jtag something? If you have a shared library at all you’re on something with a lot more horsepower than a ‘very weak’ embedded system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdb comes with a program called `gcore`, which will generate a core file from the running process.

Many systems nowadays disable core files by default (`ulimit -c` in a shell will show 0). Use the `ulimit -c unlimited` shell command, then run your process in the same shell (these limits are inherited from the parent process. If you start your process some other way than directly from the shell, you will need to find out how to set them there. e.g., `LimitCORE=` in a systemd unit file).

Once your process gets into the bad state, run `gcore` on its process ID. You can then copy it to your workstation and load it into gdb (`gdb <executable> <core-file>`). You can then view the stack trace and other state as of the moment the core dump was taken.

Comment: My device is using ARM, when I run gcore on it, I receive the following error, any idea? "gcore: GDB binary (./arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gdb) not found"

Comment: You must have the gdb binary also in your PATH... gcore is part of the gdb package, so I'm not sure how you have only one but not the other.

If you can't resolve that easily, and you're okay with killing the process, then send it the abort signal (`kill -ABRT <pid>`). It should write the core file to its current working directory, then terminate.

Comment: gdb binary is way too big for my tiny embedded device. Therefore, I used gdbserver on target machine (my embedded device), connect it with gdb on my PC (host machine) and run gcore from there, core dump file is also generated on host machine side.